# Macro button to change filter

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007

I want to have buttons to change my excel filter.

I filter my fields with `contains=something` so each button should change that something text.

Button1: change filter to `contains=button1`

Button2: change filter to `contains=button2`

and so on..

Comment: Agree with @JMax above. Also as a starting point, if you haven't already done this, run the Macro recorder, make the changes to the filter that you want, and then look at the code generated by the recorder.

Comment: wow I did not know it was so easy. I was looking for a start point and after JMax's comment I saw there was a button called save macro. Thanks for the comments though. This thread can be deleted I guess.

Comment: @Ghokun: you can either delete it by yourself if you think it is not worth it (you have your own delete button at the bottom of your question) or *better*, you can post your answer to your own question and accept it, that can help further readers that would have the same question as you had :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I found answer myself, I put it here for future help.

```
    Sub AI()

    '            sheet range and which field you want to filter and criteria to search
        ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$Z$203").AutoFilter Field:=14, Criteria1:="stringtomatch"
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make it easier by referencing the the filter search string from a cell as follows.

```
Sub Filter()
    Dim searchField As String

    searchField = "=*" & Range("H2") & "*"

    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$3:$H$18401").AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:= _
        searchField, Operator:=xlAnd

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add a HLOOKUP in e.g. cell h2 that would be controlled by the spin button changing field F1. in this case we have a full solution

```
 =HLOOKUP(h2;h2:h100;F1;0)
```

This is combined with this macro provided above:

```
Sub Filter()
     Dim searchField As String

     searchField = "=*" & Range("H2") & "*"

    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$3:$H$18401").AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:= _
        searchField, Operator:=xlAnd

 End Sub
```